# Compute the double sum with binomial coefficients: $ \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n, \ i+j\leq n }\binom{i+j}{i} x^i y^j $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to compute the double sum :

> $$ \sum_{1\leq i, j\leq n, \ i+j\leq n }\binom{i+j}{i} x^i y^j $$

Here $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, although it is not mentioned in the source.

***Note:*** a typo in the original question was to evaluate the sum for $1 \le i \le j \le n$ instead of $1 \le i,j \le n$.

I've thought about Newton's theorem, about rewriting it as : $$ \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1, i+j \leq n}^j \begin{pmatrix}i+j\\ j \end{pmatrix} x^iy^j $$

But it was in vain, the derivatives either do not lead to something helpful.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe there is a simple formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know how to answer the question if
the $i\leq j$ condition is dropped (perhaps that’s a typo in your question ?). If 
one denotes the sum by $S$, one can write

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
S&=&\sum_{t=2}^{n} \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n, i+j=t  }\binom{i+j}{i}x^iy^{j}=
\sum_{t=2}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{t-1}\binom{t}{i}x^iy^{t-i} \\
&=&
\sum_{t=2}^{n} (x+y)^t-(x^t)-(y^t)=\frac{(x+y)^2-(x+y)^{n+1}}{1-(x+y)}-
\frac{x^2-x^{n+1}}{1-x}-\frac{y^2-y^{n+1}}{1-y}
\end{array}
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't the exponents equal to $n+2$ be $n+1$?

Comment: Can we solve the problem about $ i\leq j $ by considering the number of solutions(couples) of $i+j=t$ ? $i,j,t \in \mathbb{N^*}$

Comment: It doesn't seem so, since each such solution contributes in a different way to the sum. There is no symmetry. E.g. for $(i,j)=(2,5)$ you have a term of $\binom{7}{2}x^2y^5$ while for $(i,j)=(5,2)$ you have a term of $\binom{7}{2}x^5y^2$.

Comment: @posilon corrected, thanks.